# bisection method program in c why do i need while before an if statement?

Tags: c

I'm new and trying to learn bisection method in c. Here is my program so far:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>

 double f(double x)
 {
      return  pow(x,2)-2;
 }
 main()
 {
      double x1, x2, x3, i;
      do
      {
           printf("Enter a number for x1 and x2");
           scanf("%lf  %lf", &x1, &x2);
      }
      if(f(x1)*f(x2)<0);  /* **<--- if statement line 16** */

      for(i=0;i<100;i++)
      {
           x3=(x1+x2)/2;

           if (f(x1)*f(x3)<0)
               x2=x3;
           else
               x1=x3;

           if(f(x3)==0 || fabs(x1-x2)<0.000001) /* check if the roots*/
            break;

      }

      print("x=%lf \n",x3);
      return 0;
 }
```

and I got this error message.

```
   16:error: expected âwhileâ before âifâ
```

I know my code is janky, but I'm still learning. 
I don't know why its expected to have a while loop before an if loop there.

Answer (score 1):

Your `do` loop:

```
do {
    printf("Enter a number for x1 and x2");
    scanf("%lf  %lf", &x1, &x2);
}
```

is missing the closing `while (...);` condition.

Probably you wanted to write `while` instead of `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Right before the `if`, you have this:

```
  do
  {
       printf("Enter a number for x1 and x2");
       scanf("%lf  %lf", &x1, &x2);
  }
  if(f(x1)*f(x2)<0);
```

You have the start of a `do...while` loop, but there's no `while` condition.  You also have an `if` with no statement that follows.  You probably wanted to use `while` here instead of `if`:

```
  do
  {
       printf("Enter a number for x1 and x2");
       scanf("%lf  %lf", &x1, &x2);
  }
  while (f(x1)*f(x2)<0);
```

Comment: @demo Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
if(f(x1)*f(x2)<0);  /* **<--- if statement line 16** */
```

should be:

```
while (f(x1)*f(x2)<0);  /* **<--- if statement line 16** */
```